# Why only the first function inside onclick event handler sets innertext properly and the second one gives NaN?

Tags: javascript, dom

I tried to create a basic expense tracker website using DOM manipulation. When I am calling two function at a time in an onClick event handler, the one I called at first place does it's job fine to set the innertext in html. But the function I call after first one sets the innerText as NaN! It behaves same even if I replace the position of the function. Here is my HTML & JS code in order.

```js
function expenseCalculation() {

  expenseAndBalance("expense");
  expenseAndBalance("balance");

}

// expense calculation shared function
function calculationReuse(inputId) {
  const expneseInput = document.getElementById(inputId);
  const expneseInputValue = expneseInput.value;
  const expenseAmount = parseFloat(expneseInputValue);
  expneseInput.value = "";
  return expenseAmount;
}
// Getting Total expenses & balance Text
function expenseAndBalance(textId) {
  const income = calculationReuse("income-input");
  const foodExpense = calculationReuse("food-input");
  const rentExpnese = calculationReuse("rent-input");
  const clothesExpense = calculationReuse("clothes-input");
  const totalExpense = foodExpense + rentExpnese + clothesExpense;
  const balance = income - totalExpense;
  const moneyAmount = document.getElementById(textId);
  const moneyAmountText = moneyAmount.innerText;
  const moneyAmountNumber = parseFloat(moneyAmountText);
  if (textId == "expense") {
    moneyAmount.innerText = totalExpense;
  } else {
    moneyAmount.innerText = balance;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1 class="text-3xl font-semibold text-emerald-500 text-center mt-12 heading">
    Expense Tracker 
  </h1>
</header>
<main>
  <!-- Image part -->
  <div class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-4 mt-12 mx-8 media-query">
    <div class="money-pic">
      <img src="images/coins-paper-money-globe-white-statistic-form-background.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
    <!-- Calculation part -->
    <div class="calculation-part bg-slate-200">
      <div class="texts-and-inputs mx-auto">
        <h3 class="text-center font-semibold text-lg my-4">Income</h3>

        <div class="calculation-inputs text-center">
          <h2 class="inline text-base font-medium">Income:</h2>
          <input class="bg-neutral-300" type="text" name="" id="income-input" />
          <h3 class="text-center font-semibold text-lg my-4">Expenses</h3>
          <div class="block mb-2">
            <h2 class="inline text-base font-medium">Food:</h2>
            <input class="bg-neutral-300" type="text" name="" id="food-input" />
          </div>
          <div class="block mb-2">
            <h2 class="inline text-base font-medium">Rent:</h2>
            <input class="bg-neutral-300" type="text" name="" id="rent-input" />
          </div>
          <div class="block mb-2">
            <h2 class="inline text-base font-medium">Clothes:</h2>
            <input class="bg-neutral-300" type="text" name="" id="clothes-input" />
          </div>
          <button onclick="expenseCalculation()" class="px-4 py-2 my-2 rounded-sm bg-sky-500 text-white">
                    Calculate
                  </button>
          <h3 class="text-center font-semibold text-lg my-2">
            Total Expenses: <span id="expense">5500</span>
          </h3>
          <h3 class="text-center font-semibold text-lg my-2">
            Balance: <span id="balance">4500</span>
          </h3>
          <div class="block mb-2">
            <h2 class="inline text-base font-medium">Save:</h2>
            <input class="bg-neutral-300 w-14" type="text" name="" id="save-input" />
            <span class="font-semibold text-lg">%</span>
            <button class="px-2 py-1 my-2 rounded-sm bg-sky-500 text-white">
                      Save
                    </button>
            <h3 class="text-center font-semibold text-lg my-2">
              Saving amount: 2000
            </h3>
            <h3 class="text-center font-semibold text-lg my-2 pb-4">
              Remaining balance: 2500
            </h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because `calculationReuse` clears all the inputs in `expneseInput.value = "";`.

You're calling expenseAndBalance twice with different textIds. The first call works as expected, **clears all the inputs because of the reason above**, and then when the second `expenseAndBalance("balance")` happens, all the expense/balnce inputs are empty, leading to NaN parseFloat values.

What I'd suggest is remove `expneseInput.value = "";` from `calculationReuse` and putting it in the original click event function like so:

```
function expenseCalculation() {
  expenseAndBalance("expense");
  expenseAndBalance("balance");
  clearInputs();
}

function clearInputs() {
document.getElementById('income-input').value = '';
document.getElementById('food-input').value = '';
document.getElementById('rent-input').value = '';
document.getElementById('clothes-input').value = '';
}

function calculationReuse(inputId) {
  const expneseInput = document.getElementById(inputId);
  const expneseInputValue = expneseInput.value;
  return parseFloat(expneseInputValue);
}
```

This way, you only clear all the inputs once you're done calculating things the way you need to.

Answer (score 0):

You first call `expenseAndBalance` to calculate `expense`, clear the input fields to `""` in `calculationReuse`, and call it again to calculate `balance`. When `expenseAndBalance` runs for the second time, all the input fields have the value set to `""`, hence `NaN`.

I see no reason to do the entire calculation twice. You calculate both `totalExpense` and `balance` in both function calls. Better to update both fields at once in a single function call.

```js
function expenseCalculation() {

  expenseAndBalance();

}

// expense calculation shared function
function calculationReuse(inputId) {
  const expneseInput = document.getElementById(inputId);
  const expneseInputValue = expneseInput.value;
  const expenseAmount = parseFloat(expneseInputValue);
  expneseInput.value = "";
  return expenseAmount;
}
// Getting Total expenses & balance Text
function expenseAndBalance() {
  const income = calculationReuse("income-input");
  const foodExpense = calculationReuse("food-input");
  const rentExpnese = calculationReuse("rent-input");
  const clothesExpense = calculationReuse("clothes-input");

  const totalExpense = foodExpense + rentExpnese + clothesExpense;
  const balance = income - totalExpense;


  document.getElementById("expense").innerText = totalExpense;

  document.getElementById("balance").innerText = balance;

}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1 class="text-3xl font-semibold text-emerald-500 text-center mt-12 heading">
    Expense Tracker 
  </h1>
</header>
<main>
  <!-- Image part -->
  <div class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-4 mt-12 mx-8 media-query">
    <div class="money-pic">
      <img src="images/coins-paper-money-globe-white-statistic-form-background.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
    <!-- Calculation part -->
    <div class="calculation-part bg-slate-200">
      <div class="texts-and-inputs mx-auto">
        <h3 class="text-center font-semibold text-lg my-4">Income</h3>

        <div class="calculation-inputs text-center">
          <h2 class="inline text-base font-medium">Income:</h2>
          <input class="bg-neutral-300" type="text" name="" id="income-input" />
          <h3 class="text-center font-semibold text-lg my-4">Expenses</h3>
          <div class="block mb-2">
            <h2 class="inline text-base font-medium">Food:</h2>
            <input class="bg-neutral-300" type="text" name="" id="food-input" />
          </div>
          <div class="block mb-2">
            <h2 class="inline text-base font-medium">Rent:</h2>
            <input class="bg-neutral-300" type="text" name="" id="rent-input" />
          </div>
          <div class="block mb-2">
            <h2 class="inline text-base font-medium">Clothes:</h2>
            <input class="bg-neutral-300" type="text" name="" id="clothes-input" />
          </div>
          <button onclick="expenseCalculation()" class="px-4 py-2 my-2 rounded-sm bg-sky-500 text-white">
                    Calculate
                  </button>
          <h3 class="text-center font-semibold text-lg my-2">
            Total Expenses: <span id="expense">5500</span>
          </h3>
          <h3 class="text-center font-semibold text-lg my-2">
            Balance: <span id="balance">4500</span>
          </h3>
          <div class="block mb-2">
            <h2 class="inline text-base font-medium">Save:</h2>
            <input class="bg-neutral-300 w-14" type="text" name="" id="save-input" />
            <span class="font-semibold text-lg">%</span>
            <button class="px-2 py-1 my-2 rounded-sm bg-sky-500 text-white">
                      Save
                    </button>
            <h3 class="text-center font-semibold text-lg my-2">
              Saving amount: 2000
            </h3>
            <h3 class="text-center font-semibold text-lg my-2 pb-4">
              Remaining balance: 2500
            </h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```